# Errors using python's ECDSA lib to sign AWS messages

Tags: python, digital-signature, ecdsa

I'm signing my messages using my code below:

```
def sign_msg_hash(self, msg_hash: HexBytes):
        signature = self._kms_client.sign(
            KeyId=self._key_id,
            Message=msg_hash,
            MessageType="DIGEST",
            SigningAlgorithm="ECDSA_SHA_256",
        )
        act_signature = signature["Signature"]
        
        return (act_signature)
```

However, when trying to do the following:

```
 sign = kms.sign_msg_hash(transaction)
vks = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_public_key_recovery_with_digest(
                sign, transaction, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1, hashfunc=sha256
            )
```

I get the following error:

```
ecdsa.util.MalformedSignature: Invalid length of signature, expected 64 bytes long, provided string is 72 bytes long
```

Now, when trying to use `sign[:64]` instead, it sometimes works but at other times gives me the following error:

```
raise SquareRootError("%d has no square root modulo %d" % (a, p))
ecdsa.numbertheory.SquareRootError: 6631794589973073742270549970789085262483305971731159368608959895351281521222 has no square root modulo 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
```

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the encoding of the signature from the KMS or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some digging, it turned it out it was a matter of encodings, as the kms sign function returns the signature in DER format.

Hence, what I did was the following:

1. I took the signature and split it, and got the `r` and `s` values as follows:

   ```
   decoding=ecdsa.util.sigdecode_der(sign,int("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141",16))
   ```
2. I then concatenated the result (note that r and s should be in big-endian order):

   ```
   new_sign = decoding[0].to_bytes(32, byteorder= 'big') + decoding[1].to_bytes(32, byteorder= 'big')
   ```
3. I then used the new sign:

   ```
   vks = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_public_key_recovery_with_digest(
               new_sign, transaction, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1, hashfunc=sha256
         )
   ```

Another thing I encountered was with `kms_client.get_public_key()`

1. First call the method:

   ```
   kms_pub_key_bytes = kms_client.get_public_key(KeyId=key_id)["PublicKey"]
   ```
2. Then get the last 128 chars which are essentially the r and s values

   ```
   kms_pre_sha3 = kms_pub_key_bytes.hex()[-128:]
   ```

Then do what you want with the public key.

[Related blog post on Medium](https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/der-asn-1-and-crypto-formatting-43c33d8fe639)